# Custom breadbrumbs for individual product pages via menu

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I have this landing page:
[landing page for website](http://twinklewinkle.co.uk/newsite/wordpress/autumn-winter-collection/autumnwinter-baby-and-toddler-blanket/)

Currently I have the following breadcrumb if I click on of the products on that page:

Home/Shop/Products/Fox in the Forest Glade

and what I really would like to achieve is to replace those breadcrumbs with navigation, like via the menu, so like this:

Home/Autumn & Winter Collection/Baby and Toddler Blanket/Fox in the Forest Glade

Forgive me, but I have no idea how to achieve this. Obviously not all products would have the same breadcrumb, they would differ as navigation differs.

Can someone let me know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check this plugin, i guess your all requirement get fulfilled in this.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/

Comment: I checked it out, but does it do what a really want?

Comment: Yeah this wasn't what I meant, sorry/